# How to parse data and then load it into pickerView?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I need to get JSON data and put it in a pickerView on my ViewController.
The problem is that my app calls parse function AFTER it gets through all protocol functions and therefore loads pickerView with nothing.
What is the best way to get data firstly and then load it into pickerView?

Thanks!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getCompanyList()     // This is parse function which loads dictionary companiesListDict



private var companiesListDict: [String: String] = [:]



    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return self.companiesListDict.keys.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    return Array(self.companiesListDict.keys)[row]
}
```

UPD:

```
 private func getCompanyList () {
    if let url = URL(string: "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/list/infocus") {
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {data, response, error in
            guard
                error == nil,
                (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200,
                let data = data
                else {
                    print("‼️ Network error")
                    return
            }

            self.parseCompanyList(data: data)
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}

private func parseCompanyList(data: Data) {
    do {
        let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)

        guard
            let companyList = jsonObject as? [Any]
          else {print("‼️ Invalid JSON format"); return}

        for company in companyList {

            guard
            let companyJson = company as? [String: Any],
            let companyName = companyJson["companyName"] as? String,
            let companyLabel = companyJson["symbol"] as? String
                else {print("‼️ Invalid JSON format"); return}

            self.companiesListDict[companyName] = companyLabel
        }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.companyPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
                self.companyPickerView.isHidden = false

            }

    }

    catch {
        print("JSON parsing error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to call `reloadAllComponents` once you have the data. You could hide the pickerview until you have loaded the data.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to call reloadAllComponents 100 times in different places and functions, still nothing. Will try again.

Comment: You will need to do it in `getCompanyList` in the closure where you parse the data from the server and load it into the array. Make sure you dispatch the reload on the main queue.

Comment: @Paulw11 I put reloadAllComponents into closure just after parse and it works now, but I got another problem: initially my dictionary is empty and it crashes because has noting in func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int)

Comment: @MaksimSugak Since your question is now completely different, please completely rewrite your question reflecting your actual current issue.